# How is it possible to generate geometries using space folding?

Tags: transformations, geometry

There is a [TED presentation](https://www.ted.com/talks/michael_hansmeyer_building_unimaginable_shapes), where we see really good looking geometries, which are generated using space folding.

I get the general idea, that we start from a basic geometry like a cube, and then apply linear transformations and conditional foldings (reflecting a point on a plane). I tried it, but my results were not really good looking.

I am looking for the algorithm, to generate geometries like that. But by guessing I can not progress further. Unfortunately I was not able to find articles, explaining it.

This is an example from the video:

[image: before folding]

[image: after folding]

Comment: It sounds vaguely like using [signed distance fields](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s8nFqwOho-s) to generate geometry. However I've never heard of "folding" in this context. I would guess it's a specific technique invented by the guy who did the talk, and if he hasn't published any more details then it may not be feasible to reproduce his results closely.

Comment: I have seen the TED talk now, and I really want to know how it is done. This must be a known techinque?